# Customizing cells in UITableView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Straight forward question: How can i make nice shaped cells like this programmatically for iOS 7?

[image: Example]

Comment: Define *nice-shaped*.

Comment: you can inherit UITableViewCell

Comment: Normally, the cells would extend to the corners of the display, but not in this example. I wonder how it can be done trough code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grouped table cells. Checkout these links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/tableviewstyles/tableviewcharacteristics.html

Comment: Doesn't grouped table cells require the tableview to be static?

Comment: Nope. They can be dynamic